# Camera cannot detect face with medium resolution in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-mlkit

I'm making an app can detect face in flutter with firebase-ml-vision package but the it can detect with every resolution but medium. It's a best solution for my app since with medium resolution, the quality of image is not too low but still keep the performance smooth.

Is that a bug? This is my code:

```
Center(
    child: Container(
      child: RotatedBox(
        quarterTurns:
        (MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .orientation == Orientation.landscape)
            ? 3
            : 0,
        child: CustomPaint(
          foregroundPainter:
          (faces.isEmpty) ? null : MyPainter(faces, imageSize),
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: CameraPreview(controller),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

I have an idea that I can use an camera controller with low resolution to detect and other camera with high resolution to display. Is it okay to have 2 camera controller in a same page?